# Alternatives to global variables / singletons for changing behavior when coming from different ViewControllers in iOS.

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, global-variables

There are many questions already on SO about alternatives to global variables.  I'm hoping this question is specific enough to a scenario to garner a response.

I'm (incorrectly) relying on 10+ global variables that, after segueing to a new ViewController or RestAPI completion handler, are used to differentiate behavior.

Example:

```
var comingFromRegister: Bool = false
var comingFromMenuToUpdateAddress: Bool = false 
var comingFromCancelOrderFromOrdersVC: Bool = false
```

I'm curious what the best approach is to move away from global variables.  I can create a singleton class called ComingFrom to handle these scenarios such as:

```
final class ComingFrom {
    static let shared = ComingFrom()

    var register: Bool = false
    var menuToUpdateAddress: Bool = false
    var cancelOrderFromOrdersVC: Bool = false

    private init() {}
}
```

Because there are a lot of downsides to relying on singletons what is a better approach for these scenarios?

Comment: I think it all depends on your software architectural pattern. For example, if you are using MVVM, you can pass the value into the view model or something.

Comment: For your scenario delegation pattern works too.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your architecture. For your case, seems enum is better.